# set up vuetify v-expansion-panel-header to use ellipsis once text becomes too long instead of resizing

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify's 2 v-expansion-panels. I have the header bound to an input field in the content of the v-expansion-panel. I want the header to only display the amount of text that correlates to the expansion panels width when initialized and then use ellipsis to show that there is more text. It seems that out of the box the expansion panel will keep extending past the original width to accommodate the growing title. I've tried text-overflow:ellipsis a lot and also making the display a block as opposed to flex but haven't had any success.

```
   <v-expansion-panel active-class="panel-active">
                    <v-expansion-panel-header class="pa-0 span-title">
                        <template #actions>
                            <v-icon color="primary"> $expand </v-icon>
                            <slot
                                name="actions"
                                :item="panelItem"
                                :index="index"
                            >
                                <v-btn
                                    v-if="close"
                                    text
                                    outlined
                                    icon
                                    tile
                                    large
                                    @click.native.stop="onClose(index)"
                                >
                                    <v-icon class="no-rotate">
                                        {{ closeIcon }}
                                    </v-icon>
                                </v-btn>
                            </slot>
                        </template>

                        <span class="panel-drag-handle">
                            <v-btn icon>
                                <v-icon>mdi-drag-vertical</v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                            <slot
                                name="header"
                                class="span-title"
                                :item="panelItem"
                                :index="index"
                            >
                            </slot>
                        </span>
                        <v-spacer />
                    </v-expansion-panel-header>

<style>
.span-title {
    text-overflow: ellipsis
}
```